# The genus of hyperplane sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces, schemes

Let $S$ be a connected smooth projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $\Sigma$ be the complete linear system of  a very ample divisor $D$ on $S$, and  let $d=\dim(\Sigma)$ be the dimension of $\Sigma$.
Recall that $\Sigma$ can be identified with $(\mathbb{P}^d)^*$, the dual of the projective space $\mathbb{P}^d$, which parametrizes hyperplanes in  $\mathbb{P}^d$.

For each close point $t\in\Sigma$, let $H_t$ be the corresponding hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^d$ and let  $C_t=S\cap H_t$ the corresponding hyperplane section  of $S$. (Note that since $S$ is a surface, $C_t$ is a curve on $S$).

I would like to know what is the behaviour of the genus   $g(C_t)$ of the smooth curves $C_t$ (on $S$) which are members of the linear system $\Sigma$. I mean, Do all the members $C_t$ that are smooth have the same genus? or these members can have different genus?

Comment: All smooth sections have the same genus $g$, given by the adjunction formula: $g=1+\frac{1}{2}(D^2+D\cdot K_S) $.

Comment: Dear @abx Thank you for your answer! So, this  implies that the Jacobians $J_t$ of all the smooth curves $C_t$ have the same dimension, right?  However, by the definition of the Jacobian of a curve, the Jacobians are not necessarily isomorphic, right?

Comment: Yes and yes....

Comment: Dear @abx thank you for your answer! Another question: I think that the curve $C_{\overline{\eta}}$ corresponding to the geometric generic point $\overline{\eta}$ of  $(\mathbb{P}^d)^*$ is always assumed  to be smooth. If  I am correct, I would like to know why $C_{\overline{\eta}}$ is smooht?

Comment: Look for Bertini theorem.

Comment: Dear @abx thank you! I will do. On the other hand, I would like to know  if  the  curve $C_{\overline{\eta}}$ parametrized by the geometric generic point $\overline{\eta}$ of $(\mathbb{P}^d)^*$ has  special properties in comparison  to the other curves $C_t$ parametrized by the closed point $t$ in $(\mathbb{P}^d)^*$?

Comment: Depends which properties you are looking for. There are many properties such that if they hold for $C_{\bar{\eta }}$, then they hold for $t$ in a (Zariski) open subset of $(\mathbb{P}^d)^*$.

Comment: Dear @abx Thank you  for your answer! Any interesting reference to learn more about  your last comment?

Comment: This [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210858/geometric-generic-fibre) (and its answer) should be of interest to you.

Comment: Dear @abx Thank you!